# Timezone independent dates javascript

Tags: javascript, date, react-redux, timezone, date-fns

Using javascript/react native + redux i need to save timestamps in a time format that is aware of local time when saving the date, but unaware when reading the same date in another timezone.

Take a hypothetical user that travels west around the world in one day, saving a time stamp every hour, all i different timezones, all at 2021-01-30 at 18:00 hours local time. Resulting in 24 timestamps at 18:00.

Using a function in the likes of [isWithinInterval](https://date-fns.org/v2.16.1/docs/isWithinInterval) from [date-fns](https://date-fns.org/v2.16.1/docs/isWithinInterval) in a similar fashion as below, all timestamps should return true.

```
isWithinInterval(
  timestamp,
  {start: new Date(2021,0,30,17,30}, end: new Date(2021,0,30,18,30)}, 
) // -> true
```

How do one go about doing this? Preferrably in a react-redux compatiable (serializable) way. By default, your date object will be saved in UTC based on the local time on your device.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601 `2021-01-30T18:00:00+00:00` is a timestamp format containing the timezone. You could store timestamps as `2021-01-30T18:00:00+00:00`, `2021-01-30T18:00:00+01:00`, `2021-01-30T18:00:00+02:00`, ... and remove the timezone for the check.

Comment: @ThomasSablik—you're on the right track, but the traveller would have to start at the international date line at +14 (Line Islands) and travel west, not east. Starting at 18:00:00+0 and going east for 1 hour means the local time would be 20:00:00+1 (1 hour for the zone and 1 for the travel), the times compound. Travelling west they cancel. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had such a hard time to wrap my head around the date objects that it took a long time for me to understand that this problem is actually what "date-fns-tz" package is all about. This is how i'm currently solving it:

1. Create a utc-time identical to the local time
   using:

```
import {zonedTimeToUtc} from "date-fns-tz"
const myDate = new Date()  // eg 2021-02-03 10:00 UTC +5
const localTimeIdenticalUtc = zonedTimeToUtc(localDateObject, localTimeZone)  // 2021-02-03 10:00 UTC +-0
```

2. When i want to use the UTC-date, i transfer it back to an identical localDate for whatever time zone i am in.

```
    import {utcToZonedTime } from "date-fns-tz"
    const zonedTimeToUtc(localTimeIdenticalUtc, localTimeZone) // 2021-02-03 10:00 UTC +5
```